# Visual editor is bank on my Wordpress staging

Tags: wordpress, visual-editor

I have a website which was built on Wordpress and Woocommerce

- Main site: domain.com
- Staging site: staging.domain.com

Environment:
- Source code run on docker : WordPress:4.9.7-php7.2-apache
- Mysql: 5.6.39

I use theme Flatsome, some days ago, I upgraded Woocommerce, everything worked fine, but only Visual Editor was blank.

I cloned DB from live site to the staging site and rollback code, changed theme to 'Twenty Sixteen' but the Visual Editor still is empty now.

Mysql is same, Webserver is same, because it runs on docker. But the Visual Editor does not work

Please help!

Comment: Try installing classi editor plugin?

Comment: @Earid I will try, but on same env, on my production site, visual editor still work well

Comment: You using 4.7 wp (current version is 5.3 , they have some major changes) & updated woo-commerce, this is the causing issue. I can assume your stag & main site do not have all similar versions of the plugin & wp version.

Comment: @Earid I found the issue. I missed config DB_CHARSET on docker env.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

On my staging site, I missed config DB_CHARSET.